# nodeValue and filtered characters?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, nodevalue

I'm trying to make a script to verify if a nodeValue is in the html document

```
var myVar= document.getElementsByTagName("b");
for (var i = 0; i < myVar.length; i++) {
  var pumpkin = myVar[i].firstChild;  
  if(pumpkin.nodeValue == "Some text")
  {
    alert("exists");
  }
}
```

It doesn't work if the text I want to find contains filtered characters like `&nbsp;` instead of spaces.
When I'm looking with DOM Inspector those characters are not there (there are normal spaces instead), but when I look page source they are.

I tried

```
if(pumpkin.nodeValue == "Some text")
```

and

```
if(pumpkin.nodeValue == "Some&nbsp;text")
```

but both failed...
Anyone have an idea?

(it works fine when the text I want to find doesn't contains these characters in the source code).
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with help of `regular expression` because `&nbsp;`'s corresponding character code is `160`

```
var myVar= document.getElementsByTagName("b");
for (var i = 0; i < myVar.length; i++) {
    var str = myVar[i].firstChild.nodeValue;  
    var re = new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(160), "g");
    if(str.match(re)) alert("exists");
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/pqPCT/)

Comment: I tried this and at first it was only working with IE, then I changed the "g" parameter for "i" in RexExp and it works on firefox and chrome too. But now there's another problem lol : the alert only pops once even when there's supposed to be more than one match. I tested on jsfiddle.net with the same code and it's working correctly however :S

Comment: Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/pqPCT/1/) and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/pqPCT/2/). You can store the result returned by `match ` and it's an `array`.

Comment: I think that I misexplained. I meant that when there are more than one "b" tag that contains a match, there's still just one alert that pops up. For example in : `<b>Whats&nbsp;up</b><b>not&nbsp;much</b>` there would suppose to be 2 alerts, but there's only one. I finally made it work by using the RegExpObject.test(string) method. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah it was working on JsFiddle but not on the website I wanted it to work. Maybe it is because that website is weirdly coded; I noticed that not all "b" tags are closed. Anyways, finally worked with test() method :P